# How to configure 2 foreign key references from one entity

Tags: entity-framework-6

I'm trying to setup a model for a graph with edges and nodes. Each node has a link to incoming and outgoing edges. And vice versa.

When I populate a new entity framework context with 2 Nodes and one edge between them, and then invoke SaveAllChanges(), it fails with the following error:

**Unable to determine the principal end of the 'Test.Node_Incoming' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.**

This is the SQL Server model:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Node] (
    [NodeId] INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
 );

 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Edge] (
    [EdgeId] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [StartNodeId] INT NOT NULL,
    [EndNodeId] INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([NodeId] ASC),
 );

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Edge]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Edge_EndNode] FOREIGN KEY ([EndNodeId]) REFERENCES [dbo].
 [Node] ([NodeId]);
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Edge]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Edge_StartNode] FOREIGN KEY ([StartNodeId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Node] ([NodeId]);
```

And this is the EF model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Test
{
    [Table("Node")]
    public class Node
    {
        public Node()
        {
            Incoming = new List<Edge>();
            Outgoing = new List<Edge>();
        }

        [Key, Column(Order = 0), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int NodeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("StartNodeId")]
        public virtual ICollection<Edge> Outgoing { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("EndNodeId")]
        public virtual ICollection<Edge> Incoming { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("Edge")]
    public class Edge
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int EdgeId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("StartNodeId")]
        public Node StartNodeRef { get; set; }
        public int StartNodeId { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("EndNodeId")]
        public Node EndNodeRef { get; set; }
        public int EndNodeId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Hope anyone can tell me how to fix this,

Thanks in advance!
Jeroen

Comment: Have you got any explicit mappings?

Comment: Noop, all there is is in this code.

Comment: That's strange, when I use your model and try to create a database I get a circular cascade path error. When I fix that I can insert new nodes an edges in one go.

Comment: I must admit I simplified the example but thought I kept the essence. Apparently that failed... circular ref is in the primary key of the edge table, indeed a typo. This did work for me as well in the past but at some point it stopped working in my real project. think I need to come up with a more elaborate example to make it fail...